# Find the $\log_y(x)$ given $x$ and $y$ in the form of a number.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

So I was doing logs trying to reteach myself pre-calculus and I noticed I don't remember how to turn logs in to numbers. I tried to calculate the $\log_48$ so I turned it in to $4^x=8$ and then realized that $8=4^1\sqrt{4}=4^{1.5}$. Isn't there a method to calculate the answer even when it is an irrational number?

Comment: $\sqrt4=5 $?!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest you can come is firstly expressing everything in the natural logarithm via $$\log_a b=\frac{\ln b}{\ln a}.$$

Then doing taylor expansion of the natural logarithm.